# How to use nvidia-docker without using GPU?

Tags: docker, deep-learning, nvidia-docker

I wanted to run some code on CPU only on a GPU machine. Currently I have `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES= nvidia-docker ...` but the model still will be copied to the GPU. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I believe the device control env var for use with docker is `NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` not `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`, see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/user-guide.html).